# Pandas apply a function to a column while the condition is valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe let's say:

```
          Name     Age.   Certain value   
0     Alex     50.0     12
1     Bob      12.0     45
2     Clarke   13.0     25
```

I would like to apply a function to the age column. Something like this :

```
def update_age(df):
  while df["Age"] < df["Certain Value"]:
     df["Age"] = df["Age"] * 2 

df["Age"] = df.apply(update_age,axis=1)
```

The problem that I am facing is an infinite loop. There seems to be `df["Age"]` is not updating for each iteration. Could be because of not returning the value after calculation but I have no idea how to do it.

The actual dataset is complex but I tried to simplified. Hope it is easy to understand.

Comment: Yes, that is because you're using a while loop & not defined any condition to break the look. Instead have a look at [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where)

Comment: Well, correct me if I am wrong but still, I may have to use a while loop because in Bob's case the function multiples the age with 2 and the condition is not invalid yet. So, it has to update one more time. Update, compare, update, compare - and break the loop. Do I miss something? Thanks,

Comment: Try `while (df["Age"] < df["Certain Value"]).any():`

Comment: Just make sure that you actually want to double all rows, maybe you are looking to double only the rows where age is below the cut?

Comment: Also, should you `return df` and call the function with `df = update_age(df)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that will work is this:

```
def process_row(r):
    foo = row["Age"]
    while foo < row["Certain Value"]:
        foo  = foo * 2 
    return foo
```

Now,

```
df["New_age"] = df.apply(processrow, axis=1)
df["Age"] = df["New_age"]
```